# In MySQL, can you check if a field is NULL or empty using only one comparison?

Tags: mysql, null, comparison

If I want to check to see if a field is NULL or empty using a MySQL query, I know I can do something like this:

```
column = '' OR column IS NULL
```

However, is there any way to check this without doing two separate comparisons?

Answer (score 36):

Use `COALESCE()` to 'normalize' the value (convert NULL values to an empty string);

```
WHERE COALESCE(mycolumn, '') = ''
```

Read the documentation: [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Or the other way around; convert empty strings to NULL;

```
WHERE NULLIF(mycolumn, '') IS NULL
```

Documentation: [`NULLIF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)

Of those two, I would prefer COALESCE() as it is part of the ANSI SQL standard

You can experiment with it yourself, just do this;

```
SELECT 
    mycolumn                      AS orig_value,
    COALESCE(mycolumn, '')        AS coalesce_value,
    (COALESCE(mycolumn, '') = '') AS compare_result

FROM mytable;
```

This will show the original value, the 'coalesce' value and the result of the comparison side by side for every row in the table

Comment: Would the negative version of this simply be `WHERE COALESCE(mycolumn, '') <> ''` ?

Comment: Yes, COALESCE returns the **first non-null value**. So, if `mycolumn` is `NULL`, it will return ''. If `mycolumn` is *any other value* (including an empty string), the value of `mycolumn` will be returned.

Comment: You should note, though, that using any function (including NULLIF, COALESCE, etc) on a column value in a WHERE clause might prevent the query planner from making use of any index you might have on that column.  Therefore, though longer, the OP's original SQL might perform better in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Was wondering if there is any performance difference.  Other SO posts say its probably non significant, so I'll choose COALESCE, for standard's sake (even if this term sounds barbaric and non-intuitive to me).  Btw, if anyone did bench this, it could be a nice addition.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE COALESCE(column, '') = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method without WHERE, try this..

Will select both Empty and NULL values

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(fieldname,''))  FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE NOT(column LIKE '_%')
```

Without the NOT, the value of column must at least have one character and can not be `NULL`.

EDIT: MySQL still seems to swallow the NULL value this way. This should work better:

```
WHERE IFNULL(column, '') = ''
```